# Android push notification solution if already has a connection to server

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a few apps which are dependent from server side. From there are getting they data.
The server side needed development anyhow. Server code hosting is done in our side. The client-server  communication, structure is already up.
In this state we need to implement a push notification: 
If there are new data on the server than it should be visible at user somehow.

The "standard", recommended way now is to use [Google Cloud Messaging System](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

I have a few concerns about it:

- Requires client and server side coding and bind they technology in our code. And not this is the biggest:
- Is changing relative often the technology: deprecation, and need to change our code. This is the biggest. Previous of this was something other and before that something other. In 4-5 years 3 changes is to much.

I am thinking to implement like this:

I will write **a broadcast receiver** listening when the user got internet connection. 
On Internet connection it will check the server to see if it has something new or not.
If is does than it will show a notification and job is done. If the user clicks the notification it will start the app and download the playload.
**I will use an alarm schedule**, to check the server again after 1 or 15 min or 4 hours, whatever. **There it will be no service running in background, just receivers!**

The register - unregister functionality should be done in app.

Communications to server in plus:

1. registerMyDevice(IMEI)-or username+password
2. unregisterMyDevice(IMEI)
3. isSomethingNewData()

When the client comes to server it will send his IMEI anyhow to identify, so the server will know for who need to send push.

Anybody can take Google proposed solution and prove it is better in this case than our in-house solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with that solution is that you'll add one more background process that shortens the battery life. Imagine what would happen if many app developers choose to implement your solution. A user that installs several such applications will have their battery emptied quickly. With GCM, one connection is maintained with one server, and that connection serves all applications on the device.

I believe integration with GCM is simpler than developing a push solution by yourself. The API changes always come with improvements (original GCM allowed multiple senders while C2DM didn't; the new GCM gives you user notifications and device to cloud messaging), but even if you don't choose to work with them, the old APIs still work (even if they are deprecated).

Comment: +1, "one more background process that shortens the battery life" tis is false, because the alarm manager will pop my Receiver to life. Good point: "Imagine what would happen if many app developers choose to implement your solution" well, the alarm manager will work, thread context switching-> CPU work, this good point forth an upvote, not enough motivation to switch my opinion yet:)

Comment: @matheszabi I was talking about the case where the broadcast receiver is running. If a device switches many time between WiFi and cellular data connection, or if the device disconnects and connects very often, on each connect your receiver will be executed. And once the device is connected to the internet, it's not enough to contact the server once to check if new data is available. You have to poll the server every X seconds/minutes (depending on how soon you want the user to be notified). With GCM the device would connect to your server only after it knows there's new data available.

Comment: the device from where it knows if there is new data at GCM server, if isn't checking periodically?

Comment: @matheszabi But GCM has one process on the device that does this polling (if indeed that's the mechanism used by GCM) for all apps that use GCM. That's the difference. You would be adding a process that polls your server instead of using a process that's already running on your device. In the new GCM Cloud Connection Server they even suggest that you use this connection to send messages from the device to your server, instead of opening a connection to your server, and the reason is, again, to save battery.